g++ "ignoring nonexistant directory" that does in fact exist (only with CLion + Ninja)
I have some C++ source which includes the line:
#include <Eigen/Core>

The compilation fails at this line, with the error: (my source file names/paths redacted for brevity.)
In file included from ___.h:8,
                 from ___.cpp:1:
____.hpp:5:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

The strange thing is that building this from the command line (even using the Ninja file that CLion generated) works fine.
My CMakeLists.txt includes the following:
include_directories("/usr/local/include" "/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
        "/usr/include/eigen3" "/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported"
        "include/" "include/minidnn" )

Most relevant are the two eigen-related paths. Under /usr/include/eigen3 is (I have triple checked) a folder called Eigen, within which is a file named Core. This is the reason that I believe this build system should work. As mentioned, this does work when not building through CLion.
To try and debug this, I added --verbose to the g++ flags. Here is the relresult:
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include-fixed/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/eigen3"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/include
 /home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/include/minidnn
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: 783eab82059e8c1c7db8dfb100492c35
In file included from /home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/include/minidnn/NetworkExecutor.h:8,
                 from /home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/semisync.cpp:1:
/home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/include/minidnn/ParameterContainer.h:5:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

This seems strange. Most of the directories that g++ is claiming are "nonexistant" are absolutely existant. For instance, /usr/local/include and /usr/include/eigen3 exist. The permissions on these files/directories also look acceptable:
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 100 Feb  2  2022 /usr/include/eigen3/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 584 Feb  2  2022 /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12799 Feb  2  2022 /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core

For completeness, here is the full command which is invoked by Ninja (under CLion) before it fails.
/usr/bin/g++  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/
usr/include/eigen3/unsupported -I/home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/include 
-I/home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/include/minidnn -fopenmp -g --verbose 
-std=gnu++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mininn.dir/semisync.cpp.o 
-MF CMakeFiles/mininn.dir/semisync.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mininn.dir/semisync.cpp.o 
-c /home/garby/Documents/code/cpp/shared-memory-sgd/semisync.cpp

If I run this command manually, from the terminal, that source file builds correctly(!) This, I believe, is the crux of the problem. CLion must be doing something strange when it comes to path resolution. Does it execute inside some kind of container?...
(While writing this, I discovered the answer. I'll post the question anyway, and post the answer too, just in case anyone else comes across the same problem.)

Just after I wrote that it's as if CLion is running in some kind of container, I remembered that maybe I installed it with flatpak. I usually try to avoid flatpak (due to exactly this kind of issue), but this was indeed the case here.
Flatpak restricts which directories applications may access, in this case too harshly. This explains g++ not finding the include directories.
In theory, I think the solution to this can be the following:
flatpak override --filesystem=host com.jetbrains.CLion

Although this didn't work for me... My solution was uninstalling flatpak's CLion and just running it from a downloaded tar, which I also don't enjoy.
